# Rewrite all requests to a specific subdirectory to homepage

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to push all users sending a request to a particular subdirectory back to the homepage.  E.g.;

```
http://test.example.com/apps/
http://test.example.com/apps/sd1
http://test.example.com/apps/fjwoiejf/jiejn
```

Should all rewrite to:

```
http://test.example.com
```

The web server is Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure in your htaccess file in the root of test.example.com:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^apps/(.*) http://test.example.com [R=301,L]
```

Also if you wanted to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^apps/(.*) http://test.example.com/my_new_app_directory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or Even:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^apps/(.*) http://test.example.com/sorry_dude_this_does_not_exist.php?file=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: apachectl -t throws this error for the first example; 

RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Comment: really works like a champ on my end... can you post your exact code?

Comment: Just noticed the issue.  Apache is unhappy with the space between the flags, should be [R=301,L]

Comment: nice catch, for some reason i think i typed those in by mistake updating ticket now